# Here's a weird one

Tags: network-programming, database-connection

I study both SQL and Mongodb and after a power outage at home, I can't connect to either locally. I use XE18c and SQL developer 21 for SQL and I get the silly message

> An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
>
> Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12514,
> TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
>
> > descriptor (CONNECTION_ID=(id)==)
>
> Vendor code 12514

For Mongo, I can't even start the server, not even from services.
I'm on windows 10

I guess it has to do with networking....or the mercury is in retrograde or something. Any help on the former, would be great.

UPDATE

One problem fixed. Mongodb's files got corrupted from the power outage shutdown. I was able to fixe it using --REPAIR. This Mongodb doc was very useful. [Recover a Standalone after an Unexpected Shutdown](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/)

Comment: Here's what I tried so far. 

1. check my lsnr to make sure it was ok. Check 
2 check if I could connect to other non local databases. Check
3. stop all oracle services and remount. Check
5. Tried to reconnect to HR. Nope
4. Tried to start Mongo from the console and from services. Not working

Answer (score 0):

One or more components are restarting or down; wait and re-try.

Comment: I thought that might be the case at first but unless it takes days to restart the service....not the solution for sure.